# Bios reset load optimized defaults

Tags: motherboard, bios

My system went in to a boot loop never quite finishing and now it's displaying the following screen, BUT the usb keyboard won't allow any inputs. No lights come on no matter what usb port I plug it in to. Gigabyte motherboard (don't have model number atm) No abnormal system beeps.
Suggestions?
[optimized defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mVgF.jpg)

Comment: try another keyboard?

Comment: Tried 3 different known good keyboards

Answer (score 1):

If no USB Keyboard works then changes are that USB at Boot is disabled. Your options are - find an old PS/2-Keyboard (if supported by your motherboard) or reset the BIOS by unplugging your computer, removing the CMOS-Battery, waiting for around 30s, replugging the Battery and then powering on your computer.
Now you should be able to at least enter BIOS.